# On my user page: List of questions I've answered do not update with "closed"

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

On my user page, the questions I've asked update to indicate that the question was closed.  However, the text in the link for my answers to questions do not.  Could you please add that?

Comment: By "SF.SE" do you mean Sci-Fi?  Because a lot of questions are getting closed there by moderators as the community tries to find itself.  Questions aren't supposed to be closed when they're answered.  (Commenting instead of answering because I'm not 100% sure I understand the question.)

Comment: Yep, Scifi. Am I right in saying then that questions aren't *supposed* to be closed, but *can be*?  Still, it would be useful to see that.  And I'll remove the bug tag :)

Comment: Right, only questions that don't really belong on that site should be closed.  Questions that are answered should be Accepted, which is a different state.

Comment: I know of at least one question that was closed after it was answered on that site, although that was (I think) during the private beta.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a nice feature to see. Currently when you view the answers tab in your summary page, it shows a list of answers.

Answers look like this:

[image]

And questions like this:

[image]

If one of the questions is closed, it will say so in the title of the link. What can be observed though is that the answer link text is also the title of the question. So I think it would make sense that the text of the answer link (i.e. the related question title) could also include this information.

[image]